# Selecting second monitor to open form

Tags: c#

When selecting my second monitor with this code what can I add to this method disable the form opening on the first monitor if my mouse cursor is on the first monitor display?

```
private void showOnMonitor(int showOnMonitor)
        {
            Screen[] sc;
            sc = Screen.AllScreens;
            if (showOnMonitor >= sc.Length)
            {
                showOnMonitor = 0;
            }

            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            this.Location = new Point(sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left, sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top);
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

        }
```

Comment: I want to open the form on the second monitor even if the mouse pointer is displayed on the first monitor.

Comment: Currently my code if I start the form to display on the second monitor it only displays the form on the second monitor if the mouse cursor is displayed on the second monitor using  private void Form1_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showOnMonitor(1);

        }

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Assuming you want to open the form on other monitor except the primary monitor if it has the mouse pointer. Added comments, so that you can tweak the code.
Call the function as

`showOnMonitor(5, ConvertMousePointToScreenIndex(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position));`

```
private void showOnMonitor(int showOnMonitor, Point mousePoint)
{
    Screen[] sc;
    System.Drawing.Rectangle rect;
    int mouseOnMonitor = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= Screen.AllScreens.Count(); i++)
    {
        rect = Screen.AllScreens[i - 1].Bounds;
        if (rect.Contains(mousePoint))
        {
            mouseOnMonitor = i - 1;
            break;
        }           
    }

    sc = Screen.AllScreens;
    if (showOnMonitor >= sc.Length)
    {
        showOnMonitor = 0;
    }

    if (showOnMonitor == mouseOnMonitor && showOnMonitor == 0)
    {
        //do your logic here if monitor with mouse and showOnMonitor are same i.e. disable the form opening on the monitor with mouse,
        //if such monitor should be always 0, then add the check to if condition showOnMonitor == 0 else remove this check

        //open the form on next monitor 
        //Check if more than 1 monitor available
        if (sc.Length > 1)
        {
            showOnMonitor = showOnMonitor + 1; 
            if (showOnMonitor >= sc.Length)
                showOnMonitor = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //throw exception as only 1 monitor and form should not be allowed to open on this monitor
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        this.Location = new Point(sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left, sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top);
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}
```